# How to check if a field of CtClass is of type collection in Java

Tags: java, javassist

I am trying to list down variables inside my jar file using javaassit.
I want to check if the field in a class file is of type collection. I am using "Collection.class.isAssignableForm", but it does not work because field.getType().getCLass() returns class as CtCLassType.
Is there a way to check if a CtClass field is of type Collection ?
In the similar way how to check if that field type is Serializable ?

```
CtClass loClass = ClassPool.getDefault().get(lsClassName);
CtField[] loFields = loClass.getDeclaredFields();
// iterate over fields
for(CtField field: loFields){
  // this does not work
  Collection.class.isAssignableForm(field.getType().getCLass());
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try [`subtypeOf()`](https://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/CtClass.html#subtypeOf(javassist.CtClass))?

Answer (score 0):

try to convert it into a Class first?

```
Class clazz = loClass.toClass();
Field[] loFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
...
```

Comment: Thanks. If i do this the loField.getClass() returns: 

java.lang.reflect.Field

Answer (score 0):

The `CtClass` is an abstract representation of the "real" classes and that's way you can't assume that the container class of the original field is assignable to a `java.util.Collection`.

The [javassist tutorial](https://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#toclass) shows a way to get to the "real" class. But there is a drawback described in the [javadoc](https://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/CtClass.html#toClass()): *Converts this class to a java.lang.Class object. Once this method is called, further modifications are not allowed any more.....*. If you want to change the class afterwards this maybe isn't a solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think I will have to go with some alternate approach where I can get the name of the field type and extract the collection type from that.